# Why turtlebot's SLAM failed to connect kinect devices?

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [turtlebot_navigationTutorials/Build a map with SLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM).

I run

```
  roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch 
  roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch
  rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find turtlebot_navigation`/nav_rviz.vcg
```

My picture

[image: image description]

1.Why gmapping_demo.launch show the following errors?

```
 [kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 5081, exit code 255].
 log files:      /home/sam/.ros/log/a9394afe-7a3a-11e1-80c7-20cf30a23845/kinect_laser-5*.lo     g
 respawning...
 [kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 5082, exit code 255].
 log files:      /home/sam/.ros/log/a9394afe-7a3a-11e1-80c7-20cf30a23845/kinect_laser_narro     w-6*.log
 respawning...
 [kinect_laser-5] restarting process
 process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [5164]
 [kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
 process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [5165]
 [ INFO] [1333093802.058772919, 3780.477000000]: [/openni_camera] No      devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
 [ INFO] [1333093802.110550126, 3780.544000000]: Still waiting on map...
 
 [kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 5164, exit code 255].
 log files:      /home/sam/.ros/log/a9394afe-7a3a-11e1-80c7-20cf30a23845/kinect_laser-5*.lo     g
 respawning...
 [kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 5165, exit code 255].
 log files:      /home/sam/.ros/log/a9394afe-7a3a-11e1-80c7-20cf30a23845/kinect_laser_narro     w-6*.log
 respawning...
 [kinect_laser-5] restarting process
 process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [5248]
 [kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
 process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [5249]
```

2.How to build a map on RViz?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30840/why-turtlebot%27s-slam-failed-to-connect-kinect-devices?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2012-05-31**:
deleted ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the tutorial you are using is for running turtlebot in real world applications. So when you run Gmapping it is trying to access a real kinect sensor and if you have not connected one to your machine it will not be able to run gmapping. Or maybe its due to this problem http://answers.ros.org/question/12869/building-a-map-with-slam-using-turtlebot-in-gazebo/.. Hope this helps..

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-17**:
For building a map in simulation you want to follow this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Map%20in%20TurtleBot%20Simulator